# Button(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm following a tutorial and am trying to write a program that returns a random sentence when a button is pressed. What I have come up with is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => {
  <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;
};

const getRandomInt = (max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

const App = () => {
  const anecdotes = [
    "If it hurts, do it more often",
    "Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!",
    "The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.",
    "Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.",
    "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.",
    "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.",
    "Programming without an extremely heavy use of console.log is same as if a doctor would refuse to use x-rays or blod tests when dianosing patients",
  ];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={()=>setSelected(getRandomInt(anecdotes.length()))}
        text="Press to get anecdote"
      />
      <div>{anecdotes[selected]}</div>;
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When I seem to run 'npm run' my browser displays the following error message:
'× Error: Button(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the braces in arrow function syntax which disables the automatic return. Either do `const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;` or

```js
const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `Button` component does not return anything. You probably want to do this:

```
const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => {
return (<button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>);
};
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) can omit the return statement if there are no curly braces. If there are then in that case you will have to write `return`;